Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 api create Intents with 3 languages
Basic information:

Using C#
Using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2
Able to connect to Dialogflow-es for fetch Intents
agent have 3 languages

Problems:
I run 3 languages with same IntentID one by one for the following code.
var result = await _intentsClient.GrpcClient.CreateIntentAsync(
    new CreateIntentRequest
    {     
        ParentAsAgentName = new AgentName(_jsonProjectId),
        Intent = intent,
        LanguageCode = createRequest.Lang
    });

But the training phases and texts will only exists in one language's intent.
Is there any methods that i can create intent for 3 languages?

Out of interest, why are you accessing the GrpcClient property instead of just calling _intentsClient.CreateIntentAsync?

@JonSkeet I don't know either. They just handed it over to me yesterday, I keep debugging it until i saw this part.
